# Ethernet connection not working after installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet, ip

EDIT: PROBLEM IS BACK.. 
I cant figure out a permanent and reliable way around the bug (have managed the bug to go away 2 times) my files keep duplicating themselves with a ~ after their name, so if I modify rc.local, a file named rc.local~ pops out of nowhere, I dont understand what this does.

Also I dont have a /etc/init/module-init-tools.conf file, Im modifying the script in kmod.conf...

Help is appreciated.

EDIT: Problem solved thanks to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1003297

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7, my ethernet connection works without problem in Windows but it doesn’t work in Ubuntu. I think the problem is related to drivers and doesn’t allow me to aquire/assign an ip adress.  Thank you for trying to help, Ill describe the problem ahead.

My wifi connection does work without problems.
When I desable my wifi: my network manager tries to connect using the wired connection 1 and it always returns "Disconnected - you are now offline", and then it tries to connect again and the cycle repeats (Disconnected - yo are now offline).

Diagnosis info:

> ~$ lspci | grep Ethernet
>
> 00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61
>   Ethernet (rev a2)
>
> ~$ ifconfig
>
> eth0
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:6f:26:c0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe6f:26c0/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:12 dropped:0 overruns:11 frame:1
>             TX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:27262 (27.2 KB)
>
> lo
>   Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:1679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:147779 (147.7 KB)  TX bytes:147779 (147.7 KB)

About my ethernet controller:  I dont understand much but here is the info I got:

> ~$ sudo lshw -class bridge
>
> *-bridge
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: MCP61 Ethernet
>          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>          physical id: 7
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
>          logical name: eth0
>          version: a2
>          serial: bc:5f:f4:6f:26:c0
>          size: 100000000
>          capacity: 100000000
>          width: 32 bits
>          clock: 66MHz
>          capabilities: bridge pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full latency=0 link=yes
>   maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
>          resources: irq:44 memory:eeefd000-eeefdfff ioport:d080(size=8)

Finally I managed to get a script that diagnoses your connections, here is the output when my wifi is off and Im trying to connect trough my ethernet:

**WARN: This system does not have a default route**

INFO: Host localhost answers to ICMP pings

INFO: Loopback interface is working properly

INFO: The lo interface is up

INFO: The lo interface has IP address 127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128  assigned

INFO: The lo interface has tx and rx  packets.

**INFO: The eth0 interface is up
INFO: The eth0 interface has IP address fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe6f:26c0/64  assigned
ERR: The eth0 interface has not tx or rx any packets. Link down?**

WARN: The eth0 interface has rx errors.

WARN: The wlan0 interface is down

ERR: The system does not have any nameserver configured

WARN: System does not seem to reach Internet host www.debian.org through ICMP
WARN: Cannot access web server at Internet host www.debian.org

**Thanks for reading and if you can help me out it will be greatly appreciated.**

EDIT: $sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:4
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:e0:4c:c0:c4:2c
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.16.0-34-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com  Link down. eth0 interface has rx errors. Have you tried a different network cable? Please replace `sudo lshw -class bridge` with `sudo lshw -class network` and add the output of `lsb_release -a` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I just added the info requested, thank you for your help. I want to add that the cable works perfectly when I boot Windows 7.

Comment: How can I install a driver for my "Ethernet interface product: MCP61 Ethernet vendor: NVIDIA "? I think this might solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks to whoever wrote this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1003297

Comment: It looks like the most recent version is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1281930 Please subscribe to this bug if this problem effects you. as well as perhaps https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...x/+bug/1003297 and
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1264509 sadly this one seems to expire regularly due to a lack of interest. I've posted a workaround for those in desperate need but this probably won't be fixed unless there is more consistent reporting on launchpad.

Comment: rc.local~ is a temp file your editor is creating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** I'm posting this workaround as an answer due to the number of times this has been reported as a bug only to expire shortly thereafter and resurface again.

**Test**

1. Enter Ubuntu recovery mode:
   a. Power on system and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot up for GRUB menu.

   b. Choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" > Ubuntu, [kernel version] (recovery mode)
2. Choose "root" and key in below commands:

   ```
   rmmod forcedeth
   modprobe forcedeth msi=0 msix=0
   exit
   ```
3. Choose "resume" to resume normal boot

Now the network should be OK till next boot with AM3+ CPU.

If the workaround works on your system, please modify below file to automatically run the script when boot up:

**Bug Workaround Solution:**

1. Add the line `exec rmmod forcedeth` at next line of "script" (above grep?) in the file /etc/init/module-init-tools.conf or /etc/init/kmod.conf)
2. Add the line `modprobe forcedeth msi=0 msix=0` to /etc/rc.local
3. Restart the system to verify

Sources:
Primarily Achkap post #16 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020571&page=2

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...x/+bug/1003297

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1264509

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1281930

Clue from Julian Uribe in comments.

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04 I could not find a module-init-tools.conf file, instead I modified the kmod.conf file in the same directory.

Comment: @JulianUribe  It's right where it belongs in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. What's your output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux julian-desktop 3.16.0-34-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 17:49:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I edited the post explaining how I haven’t been able to figure out the bug in a permanent fashion, I don’t understand why, but after rebooting the forcedeth fix stops working. I’m quite lost.

Comment: Does the Test still work?

Comment: I just tried it, after resuming the boot nothing changed, then I rebooted into a normal boot and its working perfectly, so I guess the test still works. Its just the permanent way of inputting these commands that I cant figure out, is the kmod.conf file equivalent to the module-init-tools.conf file??? Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: That's odd. Resuming the boot should work, and if a normal boot works, it should work consistently. I think kmod.conf is equivilent, but I'm not certain. Could you upload a copy to pastebin and give me a link?

Comment: Could you try removing the changes to kmod.conf and try the other answer? It should be an improvement for the reasons I specified. Sadly I don't have the specific hardware necessary to test. All Intel here....

Answer (score 1):

Add "forcedeth msi=0 msix=0" to /etc/modules. This way you won't have to stop the loaded module and reload it with the proper options as it sould be loaded properly to begin with.

Sources:

Previous clues in comments and other answer.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1982856.html

Comment: This was the first fix I tried, and I let the file that way so I suppose that’s not a guaranteed fix on its own.

Comment: A suggestion in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/612076/ubuntu-14-04-1-bug-issue-with-my-on-board-networking-adapter-and-the-acpi-of-m worked the first time, I hope its the fix I needed.  The suggestion was to create a forcedeth.conf file with the options.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elder, I think the modules fix used to work before, but in the new versions it doesn’t work any more, I tried that modification on its own at first, as it is suggested in the bug report I linked.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this doesn't work with the 32-bit varieties?