# Ethernet does not work with a specific cable (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have to use a static IP configuration. I just got a new ethernet cable, and it worked fine for a while. Then it stopped detecting the ethernet connnection. I mean, it would tell me that I'm connected, then as soon as I tried accessing any website it would stop detecting the connection.

I followed the advice I found in several answers on this forum, and set managed=true in my NetworkManager.conf file. This worked for a while, but now it refuses to detect the ethernet connection altogether.

It works with two other ethernet cables I've tried (borrowed from friends) but not with mine. All the cables work fine with Windows 10 though.

Are there some compatibility issues with my particular cable? Do ethernet cables come in different types?

UPDATE: One of the cables Ubuntu is fine with is a category 6 cable, while mine is a category 5e.

Comment: You shouldn't have compatibility issues.  Typically, cat5 will either be a patch or crossover cable.   If it's a manufactured cable, it will indicate the type on the wire jacket.  If it doesn't you'll be able to put the ends to end, and if the colors don't meet up, it's a crossover cable and used for more specific uses, like direct computer to computer...  You'll use a patch cable in most instances, computer to switch, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is hardware related.

Comment: Sometimes cables go bad.

Comment: @mchid It works on Windows 10 tho...

Comment: @user68186 It works on Windows 10 tho...

Answer (score 0):

it sounds similar to the [problem that I have at the moment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771832/ethernet-connection-issues). Unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution yet but I will let you know if I figure it out.
**edit**

In the meantime please could you post the output of the following commands

```
lspci | grep Ethernet 
ifconfig eth0
sudo lshw -class bridge
sudo lshw -class network
```

**edit 2**

For reference

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1003297

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1551149#p1551149

Comment: I solved it by installing the r8168 driver instead of the r8169 I had. I'll post the output of the commands for clarity as soon as I can, currently I can't access Ubuntu as I messed something up while removing Gnome 3 and got stuck in a login loop.

Comment: thanks. I still haven't been able to fix my problem. I'm considering just upgrading to 16.04 and hoping that the problem goes away (although if it's a driver issue it probably won't). Then again, the upgrade will probably be more difficult without internet access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be a problem with the r8169 driver I had. I downloaded the r8168 driver from the [Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) and now my ethernet connection works perfectly.