# Is it possible to fix my wired network connection? (lubuntu 16.04)

Tags: networking, 16.04, lubuntu, network-manager, ethernet

I can't establish wired Internet connection on my desktop pc. It tries to connect to "wired connection 1" and even if,  after minutes, it finally (not always) manages to "connect"(according to the network indicator icon on panel) , I have no Internet.. Does any solution exist?

```
:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

terminal:

```
:~$ ifconfig
enp0s4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:60:a1:87:5b  
      inet6 addr: 2a02:587:d06:c500:44ef:f096:fe1c:fcff/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::1542:7931:b71a:1a06/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a02:587:d06:c500:1070:a40c:9369:f2a1/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1984 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:45238 (45.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:213140 (213.1 KB)  TX bytes:213140 (213.1 KB)
```

terminal:

```
:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

terminal:

```
:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

terminal:

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C network
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   logical name: enp0s4
   version: 02
   serial: 00:1d:60:a1:87:5b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=half latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:fbffcc00-fbffcc7f ioport:ec00(size=128)
```

terminal:

```
:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

terminal:

```
:~$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

terminal:

```
:~$ ip -6 route show
2a02:587:d06:c500::/64 dev enp0s4  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 85777sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s4  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev enp0s4  proto static  metric 100  pref medium
```

terminal:

```
:~$ ping6 -c4 2001:4860:4860::8888
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes
From 2a02:587:d06:c500:496e:2d4f:aff4:7285 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:587:d06:c500:496e:2d4f:aff4:7285 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:587:d06:c500:496e:2d4f:aff4:7285 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:587:d06:c500:496e:2d4f:aff4:7285 icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

--- 2001:4860:4860::8888 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3015ms
```

"kalimera" is a configuration file for wirelless connection. No configuration file for Ethernet connection here. terminal:

```
: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ ls
    kalimera
```

I tried to find a solution in older posts with no luck. I have this issue since lubuntu 15.10. Recently i have installed the new version of lubuntu 16.04 which i currently use, but so far No difference. The pc is dual boot and in the other OS everything works fine. So i assume it is not a hardware issue.  I'm not exactly too familiar with linux. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This issue looks like [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611781/ethernet-connection-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1).  When I enter in recovery mode and key the command "rmmod forcedeth"  gives "error module forcedeth is not currently loaded lubuntu"

Comment: Your network interface has a global IPv6 address from a Greek internet provider assigned, so I presume it's connected to *something*. What's the output of `ip -6 route show` and can you ping public IPv6 hosts, e. g. `ping6 -c4 2001:4860:4860::8888`? If the answer is yes, try to query that host for a DNS record: `host google.com 2001:4860:4860::8888`.

Comment: I can connect to the Internet with my wireless tp-link usb adapter. Before I run any command in the terminal, I remove the usb adapter. Thanks @DavidFoerster !!

Comment: Do you have a connection configuration file for the Ethernet connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`? If not, the issue is likely to be with the “upstream” network infrastructure, meaning whatever network component sits between your computer and the internet.

Comment: The  network component, sits between my computer and the Internet, is the ADSL rooter i got from my Internet provider (and the Ethernet cable).  Ethernet works fine with windows OS on the same Deskop PC and  with ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.  Thanks a lot @DavidFoerster : )

Comment: Unless “kalimera” is the name you gave to the Ethernet connection, it seems to run with the default configuration that should get its concrete settings from the DHCP server on the router. I don't know what could prevent that from working if other machines and operating systems can establish a network connection. My only idea is to compare it with the settings of the wireless connection. Could you please establish the wireless connection, disable the wired connection and run `ifconfig`, `ip -4 route show` and `ip -6 route show`?