# Ubuntu 18.04 Not Functionning once Connected through a Wired Ethernet Connection

Tags: networking, 18.04, wired

I recently -- in reaction to pandemy -- installed a wired connection to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop:

- Dell XPS13    Intel Core i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4
- ST: D61NHR2

Once I connect, quite rapidly, in a matter of minutes the computer stops working correctly: network connection is lost, system monitor window asks for wait or shut down but shut down not possible, etc. Needs an on/off button hard restart.

As seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611781/ethernet-connection-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts), I append the results of the command

```
zzzzzzz@PDXP13-D61NHR2:~$ sudo lshw -C Network && lspci -knn | grep -i ether -A 3 && lsb_release -a && uname -a
  *-network                 
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       numéro de série: 9c:b6:d0:92:35:73
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-45-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources: irq:143 mémoire:dc000000-dc1fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 2
       nom logique: docker0
       numéro de série: 02:42:a3:d4:58:d8
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: So, your CPU is halted for some unknown reason. Let's look for that. What s the make and model of your laptop? The model part number on the serial number sticker is the best source for your PC's configuration; 'model' numbers elsewhere are often not helpful.  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I'd check if the Ethernet cable has PoE ( Power over Ethernet )  and disable it. Over-current could be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Dell USB-C to Ethernet + VGA + HDMI + USB hub had a faulty connection. I suspected the problem because an USB stick was not recognized, and I confirmed it when moving the network plug turned the network leds off.

I bought a new USB-C to Ethernet connector and the problem disappeared.